# Impute values after a column if previous column contains given value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to impute values in preceding column.
given dataset is as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    data=[[1,'NA','','','','Inactive',''],
                     [2,'NA','','Active','',''],
                     [3,'Active','Active','','',''],
                     [4,'Inactive','','','',''],
                     [5,'NA','','','','Active']] 
    df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5'])
```

what i am trying to achieve is like this :

```
    import pandas as pd
    data=[[1,'NA','NA','NA','NA','Inactive',],
                     [2,'NA','NA','Active',''],
                     [3,'Active','Active','','',''],
                     [4,'Inactive','','','',''],
                     [5,'NA','NA','NA','NA','Active']] 
    df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5'])
```

PS status go upto 260 columns and row is around 1.3M :P
I tried using this

```
    for column in df1.columns:
        if (df1[column-1]=="NA").any():
            df1[column]=df1.fillna("NA", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
for i in range(2, df1.shape[1]):
    df1.iloc[(df1.iloc[:, i - 1] == 'NA') & (df1.iloc[:, i] == ''), i] = 'NA'


print(df1)
```

Comment: i used -- df1.iloc[:, i].isnull() instead of (df1.iloc[:, i] == '')  and it worked thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

your example have typo

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,'NA','','','','Inactive'], 
        [2,'NA','','Active','',''], 
        [3,'Active','Active','','',''], 
        [4,'Inactive','','','',''], 
        [5,'NA','','','','Active']] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5'])
```

df1

```
    ID  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
0   1   NA              Inactive
1   2   NA      Active      
2   3   Active  Active          
3   4   Inactive                
4   5   NA              Active
```

**Code**

use boolean masking

```
cond1 = df1.eq('')
cond2 = df1.isin(['Inactive', 'Active']).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0)
out = df1[~(cond1 & cond2)].fillna('NA')
```

`out`

```
    ID  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
0   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  Inactive
1   2   NA  NA  Active      
2   3   Active  Active          
3   4   Inactive                
4   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  Active
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
m1 = df1.eq('')
m2 = (~m1).loc[:, ::-1].cummax(axis=1)

df1 = df1.mask(m1&m2, 'NA')

   ID        S1      S2      S3  S4        S5
0   1        NA      NA      NA  NA  Inactive
1   2        NA      NA  Active              
2   3    Active  Active                      
3   4  Inactive                              
4   5        NA      NA      NA  NA    Active
```